# Spring Rest Controller first send 201 then do service operations

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, controller, spring-boot

1. Client sends a post request to gather id for asking status of operations
2. Spring Rest Controller class handles the post request and sends 201
   created with the id
3. Spring Rest Controller class calls service class for starting operations
   with that id
   Problem: I can not return the id before starting the operations.thus client receives some information over websocket before the id is returned

   ```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/operations", method = RequestMethod.POST)
   public ResponseEntity<?> createNewSubscription{
      String id =1;
      return new ResponseEntity<>(id, HttpStatus.CREATED);
      service.doOperations(id)
   }
   ```

   I can solve the problem by creating a thread which calls my service classes and wait 100ms in the thread and when the thread is running send 201 created to client. But it is not a good solution. Maybe I can use Spring Async rest request but it is also waiting for a callback method..How can solve that problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have the response object injected into the controller method, set the status and flush it.

```
public void createNewSubscription(HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
    resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_CREATED);
    resp.flush();
    // ...
}
```

Flush sends the response code and headers to the client already. You can do your computation then either in the controller thread or asynchronously, eg. using Spring Async.

NB - with Spring Async your method annotated with `@Async` can return `void` which means it's "fire and forget" - you don't have to wait for it to complete.

Comment: thanks, first I added content length to response and then I used response.flushBuffer . Its worked